# Sequelize assocation functions have no effect

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I use the present Sequelize version and try to build the associations between two models. Should be actually pretty simple since Sequelize offers `hasMany` and `belongsTo`.

But the call has no effect at all. I tried it with a new SQL DB. The tables itself are created, just without any foreign key.

[image]

**db controller**

```
const userModel = require('../model/user')
const subjectModel = require('../model/subject')
const database = require('../db/database').sequeliceInstance

async function setupAssociations () {
  await database.sync()

  // user + subject
  userModel.hasMany(subjectModel)
  subjectModel.belongsTo(userModel)

  // subject and topic
  subjectModel.hasMany(topicModel)
  topicModel.belongsTo(subjectModel)

  // topic and question
  topicModel.hasMany(questionModel)
  questionModel.belongsTo(topicModel)

  // question and answer
  questionModel.hasMany(answerModel)
  answerModel.belongsTo(questionModel)
  return Promise.resolve()
}
```

**user.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../db/database').sequeliceInstance

const user = db.define('user', {
  // attributes
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  }
})

module.exports = user
```

**subject.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../db/database').sequeliceInstance

const subject = db.define('subject', {
  // attributes
  subjectName: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  }
})

module.exports = subject
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

`await database.sync()` has to be called at the very end of the function.